# Python path changing slashes

Tags: python

I encountered a problem in python where for some reason python is changing the type of slash when compiling, for example, if I declare this code:

```
log_dir = os.path.join(path, r"c:\Python\Test\logs", dt.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'))
```

It is resulting in this:

```
Failed to create a directory: c:\Python\Test\logs/2020-05-03-16:30:20; Invalid argument 
[Op:CreateSummaryFileWriter]
```

How can this issue be tackled?

Comment: You're better off using forward slashes.

Comment: That is because  '\' is an escape charater in Python. You want to use `/` for your path instead.

Comment: When I change them to '/' it gives me this error.. : Failed to create a directory: c:/Python/Test/logs\2020-05-03-16:37:10\train; Invalid argument [Op:CreateSummaryFileWriter]

Comment: Try using double antislash ` \\ `, that means the antislash will be interpreted as an antislash not as an escape character.

Comment: The colon ":" is not permitted in windows filenames

Comment: Yep, that was it thanks @snakecharmerb